# Prerender not giving prerendered pages when running with _escaped_fragment_= or Open Graph Object Debugger

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, prerender

I have a site running on Amazon elastic beanstalk using Nodejs.
On another EC2 instance I have setup prerender as given here https://prerender.io/documentation.

I have also added the required path in my node server:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl','http://myprerenderserverpath:8080'));
```

When I run:
http://myprerenderserverpath:8080/http://example.com/somepage

I get the prerendered pages correctly. The logs show:

```
getting images/logo.png
getting images/loader.gif
getting images/favicon.ico
...
```

and so on based on what images are there on the page.

But when I run the same using
http://example.com/somepage/?_escaped_fragment_=

I get the following logs:

```
getting http://example.com/somepage
got 200 in 10311ms for http://example.com/somepage
```

and exactly the same when I run Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger.

So my pages are not getting crawled.

What could the issue be?

Comment: That looks to be correct and since your server is serving the prerendered page it should be working correctly. What issue are you seeing?

Comment: I think the issue why Facebook Open Graph debugger is not working is got something to do with the time taken to prerender the page. I thought the difference in the logs were indicative of some error in prerendering. Also when I run http://myprerenderserverpath:8080/http://example.com/somepage atleast I see the meta content of my page loaded within 329ms but the same when run with http://example.com/somepage/?_escaped_fragment_= takes more than 10 seconds causing the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with Todd here (https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/319) , there was some URL on my page that never returned (suspecting socket.io POLL requests) causing a 10 seconds wait before timeout at the prerender.

I reduced the RESOURCE_DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT (environment variable for Prerender) to 4 seconds instead of 10 and now Facebook debugger works correctly.

prerender/lib/server.js

```
var RESOURCE_DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = process.env.RESOURCE_DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT || 10 * 1000;
```

I think whatever url was not returning or resource been waited for was not important enough in page rendering. My meta tags are set in the first 3 seconds of the load so I get the tags picked up correctly.
Not sure if this is right approach but nevertheless it makes me happy :)

Will still look for a cleaner solution.